# Been to - gone to - been in

Tags: grammar

Since I have (been - gone) to singapore, I have seen stately skyscrapers across the country.

What is the best choice?
Gone to or been to

Comment: Still there: While I have been in Singapore,  I have seen stately skyscrapers... Gone somewhere else: When I was in Singapore,  I saw stately skyscrapers...

Answer (score 0):

**Been to** is used typically of a place that someone has visited (but returned from). You might have been to Singapore several times.

**Gone to** is used typically of a place to which someone has departed and is now to be found, whether for a visit or to stay.

So, you have been to Singapore. If you were still in Singapore, and a friend asked your parents where you were, they might reply that you had gone to Singapore.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP has returned from their visit, the original sentence would necessitate the past simple because the speaker is referring to a specific point of time in the past.

> When I **went** to Singapore, I **saw** magnificent skyscrapers across the country.

I substituted *stately* with *magnificent* because that sounds more natural and idiomatic to my ears. We don't normally describe skyscrapers as being [stately](https://collocations.en-academic.com/17434/stately), more often than not it is collocated with something that looks pompous, regal or dignified e.g.  mansions, a stately home, processions and parks.